# Search similar letters in a text file and return list of valid words

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python and am wondering if someone could help me solve this problem. What I'm doing is typing a word and the program has to find them in a text file and return a list of valid words using the letters of that input string. For example, this text file has 7 words:

```
   eee
   son
   ooo
   one
   not
   nose
   monkey
```

The program should return all valid words that contain the letters from the input string **Shone**

```
   son
   one
   nose
```

So far this is what I have:

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as file:
    x = input("#: ")
    for line in file:
        if all(e in line for e in x):
            print(line)
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as file:
    x = input("#: ")
    x = x.lower()
    for line in file:
        line = line.lower()
        line = line.strip()

        temp_x = x
        is_valid=True
        for letter in line:
            if letter not in temp_x:
                is_valid = False
                break
            temp_x = temp_x.replace(letter, '', 1)
        if is_valid:
            print(line)
```

Comment: It's possible but what if the letter is repeated twice in the input, if the input string is 'book'?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Is there any way to make it case insensitive so that regardless if the input is uppercase or lowercase it will still give the same output?